# Stuck rewriting _every

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

So i'm trying to rewrite the underscore library for a class I'm taking. Every part of the test passes with exception to one. I have no idea what to do if function is not given. Any ideas?

```
_.every = function(collection, test) {
    test = false || _.identity;
    return !!_.reduce(collection, function(test2, item) {
      return test2 && test(item);
    }, true);
 };
```

Comment: you could throw an error ... `test = false || _.identity;` is same as writing `test = _.identity;` ... so, you're effectively ignoring that argument anyway

Comment: That's good to know. Thank you.